# Delete a line from XML file using bash script

Tags: xml, bash

I am trying to delete a line from XML file using SED. i.e. `sed -i "/Mansing/d" /home/test.xml` but it deleting both the lines one with having 'Mansing' and other with 'MansingTest' as in Resource name value. Any help? XML file is as below

`<a>
    <Resource name="Mansing" auth="container" url="jdbc:mysql:"" />
    <Resource name="MansingTest" auth="container" url="jdbc:mysql:"" />
    <c>
        <Test>tterer</test>
    </c>
</a>`

Comment: Use proper `xml` aware tools like `xmlstarlet` and not blunt text processing tools.

Comment: What's stopping you from changing the search regex to `/\"Mansing\"/`? But @Inian has a valid point: Use a proper tool for the job.

Comment: I agree with and appreciate your help. Though xmlstarlet does not work at my end, I will find out what module it requires on machine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this syntax fixed file.xml

```
<a>
    <Resource name="Mansing" auth="container" url="jdbc:mysql:" />
    <Resource name="MansingTest" auth="container" url="jdbc:mysql:" />
    <c>
        <Test>tterer</Test>
    </c>
</a>
```

and xmlstarlet.

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//a/Resource[@name="Mansing"]' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <Resource name="MansingTest" auth="container" url="jdbc:mysql:"/>
  <c>
    <Test>tterer</Test>
  </c>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  "/\<Mansing\>/d" filename
```